# Placing a space before a capital letter in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I thought this would be straightforward but my code below is not working, any suggestions please?

```
Function AddSpaceBeforeUpper(Rg As Range) As Integer
Dim xStr As String
Dim I As Integer
Application.Volatile
On Error Resume Next
xStr = Trim(Rg.Value)
For I = 2 To Len(xStr)
    If (Asc(Mid(xStr, I, 1)) < 91) And (Asc(Mid(xStr, I, 1)) > 64) Then xStr = Replace(xStr, Mid(xStr, I, 1), " " & Mid(xStr, I, 1))
    If (Asc(Mid(xStr, I, 1)) < 91) And (Asc(Mid(xStr, I, 1)) > 64) Then I = I + 1
Next
```

End Function

Comment: Get rid of the `On Error Resume Next`. Then, it's not clear why your function returns an `Integer`.

Comment: be careful with blanket replace: `Replace(xStr, Mid(xStr, I, 1), " " & Mid(xStr, I, 1))` if the string is `aStrongSketch` it will put two spaces in front of both `S`s

Comment: Also beware of wasting 30min like I just did trying to use the "start" parameter to `Replace()`, without first reading that "The return value of the Replace function is a string, with substitutions made, **that begins at the position specified by start and concludes at the end of the expression string**. It is not a copy of the original string from start to finish"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated you should be returning a string and not an integer, plus there is no need for `On Error Resume Next`

Also just add the character or the space and the character if it is upper case.

Also since your function does not rely on other ranges outside the one to which it is pointed it is not necessary to make it volatile.

```
Function AddSpaceBeforeUpper(Rg As Range) As String
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim I As Integer
    xStr = Trim(Rg.Value)
    AddSpaceBeforeUpper = Left(xStr, 1)
    For I = 2 To Len(xStr)
        If UCase(Mid(xStr, I, 1)) = Mid(xStr, I, 1) Then
            AddSpaceBeforeUpper = AddSpaceBeforeUpper & " " & Mid(xStr, I, 1)
        Else
            AddSpaceBeforeUpper = AddSpaceBeforeUpper & Mid(xStr, I, 1)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```